# Explain items in result of SHOW GRANT in Hive

Tags: hive

I request all grants in Hive using the command `SHOW GRANT;`

It returns a table like that:

> default   src         role1   ROLE    Create  false   1387343876000   navis
>
> default   srcpart         role1   ROLE    Update  false   1387343908000   navis

Which seems to be database, table, principal name, principal role, privilege, ???, timestamp, grantor.

Now what is this boolean value in the list?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I found it out digging into the source code. The field shows a boolean value that says if the principal may give priviliges or roles to users and groups. It is called GRANT OPTION.